# background-color defined in parent and its child, nither of them succeed

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-color

Having this html:

```css
        body {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        header {
            background-color: rgb(93, 43, 78);
            background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgb(93, 43, 78), rgb(8, 2, 50)); /* no color in background */
        }

        header nav {
            background-color: red; /* neither here, still white background */
        }

        header ul {
            list-style: none;
        }

        header li {
            float: left;
            color: black;
        }

        p {
            clear: both;
        }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>test item1</li>
                <li>test item2</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section>
        <br />
        <p>some text</p>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not able to see background nither for the `header` parent element, nor for the `nav` child element (of the `header`). Both are trying to make a background with some color or effect, but neither of them succeed. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the problems with using `float`... it takes the element out of the flow so the parent have no content and therefore no height. The workaround is the ["clearfix" hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-a-clearfix) - basically, it forces the parent to take the height of its children.

You can create a `clearfix` class and apply it to the parent of any floated elements:

```
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

**Expand to see a working example:**

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

header {
  background-color: rgb(93, 43, 78);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgb(93, 43, 78), rgb(8, 2, 50));
  /* no color in background */
}

header nav {
  background-color: red;
  /* neither here, still white background */
}

header ul {
  list-style: none;
}

header li {
  float: left;
  color: black;
}

p {
  clear: both;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="clearfix">
      <ul>
        <li>test item1</li>
        <li>test item2</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section>
    <br />
    <p>some text</p>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

### Flexbox - a modern alternative to float

However a better options these days is to use **flexbox** - you can achieve a similar effect but without the hack, and it is also more flexible (as the name suggests!)

You just need to make the direct parent of the elements (in this case the `ul`) `display: flex` and it will automatically place the elements into the available space horizontally, e.g.

**Simple Flexbox example using your code**

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

header {
  background-color: rgb(93, 43, 78);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgb(93, 43, 78), rgb(8, 2, 50));
  /* no color in background */
}

header nav {
  background-color: red;

}

header ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

header li {
  color: black;
}

p {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>test item1</li>
        <li>test item2</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section>
    <br />
    <p>some text</p>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

This is just the tip of the iceberg when it comes to the abilities of flexbox. Take a look at the references below to see what you can do!

**More about flexbox**

- [CSS Tricks:  A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
- [Mozilla MDN Web Docs: Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

Comment: What does mean `display: table`? I know only display block, inline-block or inline. What is table here?

Comment: @milanHrabos Normally you can `display:table` it to organise non-table contents to display as a table (you can [find out more here](https://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero)), but in this case it is doing nothing except making the clearfix hack work, so you can ignore it! You can see [more about the display types here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/)

Answer (score 0):

Your header doesnt seem to have a set height.

Try adding for example height: 30%; to your css in header{}.

For example:

```
header   {
background-color: red;
height: 30%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use div instead of header. Then you will se the result.

```
<div>
test text 
</div>

div {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using floats in the li element. This means the height of its parent doesn't grow to fit. The colours are there just not visible due to no height.

```css
        body {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        header {
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: rgb(93, 43, 78);
            background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgb(93, 43, 78), rgb(8, 2, 50)); /* no color in background */
        }

        header nav {
            background-color: red; /* neither here, still white background */
        }

        header ul {
            list-style: none;
        }

        header li {
            color: black;
        }

        p {
            clear: both;
        }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>test item1</li>
                <li>test item2</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section>
        <br />
        <p>some text</p>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But I want them to float, otherwise the items look like boxes